# Shortest path algorithm on an integer matrix grid does not return the expected value

Tags: java

I have an assignment to submit and I need help I will appreciate it a lot!!

I need to write a method that gets an integer matrix grid with numbers from 0 and above. 1  value in the matrix is different and contains -1. the function also gets the starting x and y in the matrix.

I need to write a recursive function that finds the shortest path from the starting x, y to the -1 value.
you can "jump" to the left' right' up and down. the condition to "jump" from one index to another is if the absolute value between the subtraction of the the 2 pairing is either 0, 1 or 2

[image]

The shortest path is 4
I cannot use while and for loops, and global variables

The function signature should be: `public static int shortestPath(int[][] drm, int i, int j)`

Thanks a lot!

Here is my try:

```java
package assignment1;

import java.util.*;

public class run {
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int shortestPath(int[][] drm, int i, int j) {

        if (drm.length == 0 || i >= drm.length || j >= drm.length || i < 0 || j < 0)
            return 0;

        if (i > 0 && j > 0 && i < drm.length - 1 && j < drm[i].length - 1) {
            if (drm[i][j - 1] == -1) {
                System.out.print("Got it! the target is on the left");
                return 2;
            }
            if (drm[i][j + 1] == -1) {
                System.out.print("Got it! the target is on the right");
                return 2;
            }
            if (drm[i - 1][j] == -1) {
                System.out.print("Got it! the target is up");
                return 2;
            }
            if (drm[i + 1][j] == -1) {
                System.out.print("Got it! the target is down");
                return 2;
            }
        }

        int temp = drm[i][j];
        int left = Integer.MAX_VALUE, right = Integer.MAX_VALUE, up = Integer.MAX_VALUE, down = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        if (isValidJump(drm, i, j, i + 1, j)) {
            System.out.print("down ");
            drm[i][j] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            down = shortestPath(drm, i + 1, j) + 1;
        }
        if (isValidJump(drm, i, j, i, j + 1)) {
            System.out.print("right ");
            drm[i][j] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            right = shortestPath(drm, i, j + 1) + 1;
        }
        if (isValidJump(drm, i, j, i, j - 1)) {
            System.out.print("left ");
            drm[i][j] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            left = shortestPath(drm, i, j - 1) + 1;
        }
        if (isValidJump(drm, i, j, i - 1, j)) {
            System.out.print("up ");
            drm[i][j] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            up = shortestPath(drm, i - 1, j) + 1;
        }

        drm[i][j] = temp;

        return Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(up, down), left), right);
    }

    public static boolean isValidJump(int[][] drm, int i, int j, int m, int n) {
        if (m < drm.length && m >= 0 && n < drm.length && n >= 0 && drm[m][n] != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            int jump = drm[m][n] - drm[i][j];

            if (jump == 0 || jump == 1 || jump == -1 || jump == -2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] drm = { { 2, 0, 1, 2, 3 }, { 2, 3, 5, 5, 4 }, { 8, -1, 6, 8, 7 }, { 3, 4, 7, 2, 4 },
                { 2, 4, 3, 1, 2 } };

        System.out.println(shortestPath(drm, 0, 0));
    }

}
```

It supposed to return 4 (shortest path)

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: "Shortest path" and graphs makes me think of Dijkstra.   You should read about it and see how you might use it for your problem.

Comment: This line is wrong: if (jump == 0 || jump == 1 || jump == -1 || jump == -2).  I'd code it is if (Math.abs(jump) <= MAX_JUMP) {}.   You should have a static final int MAX_JUMP = 2.  More succinct, and no magic numbers.

Comment: What happens if you land on a spot that has no jump that allows you to move?  Any dead ends in your matrix?  I didn't bother to check, but your code should.

Comment: What makes you think that recursion is the way to go here?  A tree is a naturally recursive data structure.  I'm not sure that this matrix is.

Comment: What if your matrix didn't have a -1 square in it?  What if there was more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this is for a class I advise you to notify your professor that you received assistance from this post on stack overflow. Neglecting to do this would be considered academic dishonestly at most universities.

Second thing is as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) suggested this is a good opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger. This is a skill that will be incredibly valuable in your academic career and in a engineering role.

### Your Code

Now looking at your code it does give the solution "4" for the case you presented which is correct. Problem is if you change the inputs the output may not give the correct answer.

This is because your code as written gives the FIRST path it finds and not the SHORTEST path.

Your logic as far as the recursion is sound and based on this code it looks like you understand the basics of recursion. Your problem is a minor logical flaw with how your are masking your data when you call your function recursively.

You should have everything you need to solve this. If you are still having problems please try to use a debugger and examine the area where you make your recursive calls.

### Solution

I advise you to try to figure this out yourself before looking at the spoilers below.

> In the code where you make your recursive calls you mask by setting `drm[i][j] = Integer.MIN_VALUE`. The problem is after each of your recursive calls return you do not set it back to the previous value with `drm[i][j] = temp` before doing the tests for your next recursive call.
>
>  What is happening is when you next call `isValidJump()` it will always return `false` because `drm[i][j]` will always be `Integer.MIN_VALUE` after your have made your first recursive call on this iteration.

How to fix:

> Put `drm[i][j] = temp` immediately after each recursive call to `shortestPath()`.